# zend_cache absolute expiration time

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-cache

I am using php with zend framework and zend_cache. I have these lines of code for this :`

```
    $frontendOptions = array ('lifetime' => 12 * 3600, 'automatic_serialization' => true );
    $backendOptions = array ('cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../tmp');
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory ( 'Core', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions );

    $CacheName = ('CACHE_NAME');
    $CacheResult = $cache->load ( $CacheName );
    if($CacheResult==false)
        echo 'no cache or chache is expired';
    else 
        var_dump($CacheResult);`
```

The problem is that when I use save function like this :

```
$cache->save($data,$CacheName);
```

I don't want the expire time to be updated. Is there any way to update cache without updating its expiration time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Zend_Cache of ZF1 stores the given lifetime as fixed expire time.
So you only have to calculate the current lifetime in base of the current time and your expire time:

```
$lifetime = $expirationTime - time();
if ($lifetime > 0) {
    $cache->save($data, $id, $tags, $lifetime);
}
```

PS: In ZF2 you have to check if the storage checks expiration in base of current time, mtime and given TTL (like the filesystem) or in base of a stored fixed expiration time (like memcache/apc).